# R Code: Root finding using steepest descend

Tags: r, numerical-methods

One of our assignments is to write a fixed step size steepest descend function to find the minimum for the Rosenbrock's function, f(x,y)=100(y-x^2)^2+(1-x)^2. We already know that the minimum occurs at (1, 1), so it's a matter of getting the function to approximate that.

I feel like I got the function going, but even after 100 thousand iterations, the minimum it found is incorrect - The final output after 100,000 iteration is approx. (0.5348, 0.2185). This number does not change as the iteration goes up. I'm sure there's something wrong I did with the function, but just couldn't quite figure out where.

```
fixed <- function(x = 4, y = 4){
  i <- 1
  si <- 0.1   ##fixed stepsize
  h <- function(x, y) {100*(y-x^2)^2+(1-x)^2} 
  dhx <- function(x, y) (-400*x*(y-x^2)-2+(2*x)) ##partial derivative for gradient
  dhy <- function(x, y) (200*(y-x^2))
  v <- c(x, y)    ## vector that contains the x and y value, which starts at (4,4)
  for (i in 0:100000){
    gradh <- c(-dhx(x,y), -dhy(x,y))  ##negative gradient to find minimum 
    di <- gradh/sqrt((dhx(x,y))^2+(dhy(x,y))^2) ##normalized direction 
    v <- v + (si*di)   ##calculating new direction
    x <- v[1]          ##breaking down the direction components to feed into the for loop
    y <- v[2]
    i <- i + 1
#    print(i)
#    print(gradh)
#    print(di)
#    print(v)
#    print(h(v[1], v[2]))
  }
  print(i)
  print(v)    ## v should be (1,1) after some iteration
}
```

Comment: Note that this Rosenbrock function is a (well-known) **counter-example** for the gradient descent method. That is, it is expected that this method goes wrong, either becoming very slow or stopping far away from the minimum.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck : Your observation is wrong. The last two terms could have been written in accordance with the derivative of the first term as `-2*(1-x)`, but arithmetically it is the same.

Comment: Your point `v` should move the distance `si=0.1` in each step, so "this number does not change" can not be completely correct. Can you print out and add the last 6 points of the iteration sequence?